# Images dont load when html get rendered in jquery

Tags: jquery, typescript, sharepoint

I've been building a "phoneBook" for a SharePoint Online solution and everything work fine, except it dont load the images.

This is the entire `html` for the user, that i enject into the page when a search is done.

```
<div class="profile">
  <a href="https://xxxxxx-my.sharepoint.com:443/PersonImmersive.aspx?accountname=i%3A0%23%2Ef%7Cmembership%7Ccla%40xxxxxx%2Edk">
    <div class="profileImg"><img class="profileImage" src="https://xxxxxx-my.sharepoint.com/User%20Photos/Profilbilleder/cla_xxxxxx_dk_MThumb.jpg"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="txt">
    <a href="https://xxxxxx-my.sharepoint.com:443/PersonImmersive.aspx?accountname=i%3A0%23%2Ef%7Cmembership%7Ccla%40xxxxxx%2Edk">
      <div class="name">Carsten Løvbo Andersen</div>
      <div class="department">Afdeling</div>
      <div class="seperator hideIT Department hideProduct Manager">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="jobtitle">SharePoint Developer</div>
    </a>
    <div class="email">
      <a href="https://xxxxxx-my.sharepoint.com:443/PersonImmersive.aspx?accountname=i%3A0%23%2Ef%7Cmembership%7Ccla%40xxxxxx%2Edk"></a><a href="cla@lavanet.dk">cla@xxxxxx.dk</a></div>
    <div class="phone">12345678</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

If I take the `image src` and paste it into the browser I can see the image without any problems.

I use `Typescript/jQuery` to get all the data from the `Search Query` and add the data to the html above, and then inject it into the page.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with the dom? If i enter the console log, there is no errors, and if I type `$('.profileImage').attr("src", "theimageurl")` then the image is visible some times.

**My TypeScript / jQuery**

```
for (let person = 0; person < usermatch.length; person++) {
    containerdata += '<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-7" tabindex="-1"><div class="profile" >' +
        '<a href="' + usermatch[person].path + '">' +
        '<div class="profileImg">' +
        '<img class="profileImage" src="' + usermatch[person].ProfileImg.replace(" ", "%20") + '">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="txt">';
    if (!(usermatch[person].Name == "null" || usermatch[person].Name == undefined)) {
        containerdata += '<div class="name">' + usermatch[person].Name + '</div>'
    };

    if (!(usermatch[person].Department == "null" || usermatch[person].Department == undefined)) {
        containerdata += '<div class="department">' + usermatch[person].Department + '</div>';
        makechar = true;
    };

    if (!(usermatch[person].JobTitle == "null" || usermatch[person].JobTitle == undefined)) {
        if (makechar) { containerdata += '<div class="seperator hideIT Department hideProduct Manager">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</div>' };
        containerdata += '<div class="jobtitle">' + usermatch[person].JobTitle + '</div>'
    };

    if (!(usermatch[person].Email == "null" || usermatch[person].Email == undefined)) {
        containerdata += '<div class="email"><a href="' + usermatch[person].Email + '">' + usermatch[person].Email + '</a></div>'
    };
    containerdata += '</a>';
    if (!(usermatch[person].Phonenumber == "null" || usermatch[person].Phonenumber == undefined)) {
        containerdata += '<div class="phone">' + usermatch[person].Phonenumber + '</div>'
    };

    containerdata += '</div>' +
        '<div style="clear:both;"></div>' +
        '</div></li>'
};
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Do anyone have an idea why i have this problem.

Comment: So when you inspect the image path, what do you see?

Comment: When i inspect the image after the search is done i see `https://xxxxxx-my.sharepoint.com/User%20Photos/Profilbilleder/cla_xxxxxx_dk_MThumb.jpg`, if i take the url and paste it into a new tab in my browser then I can see the image